# Making this function infinitely nesting based off a table

Tags: drop-down-menu, lua, world-of-warcraft

I finally solved my problem to make a dropdown menu in world of warcraft off of a table.

Now I need it to be able to nest as far down as the user supplies. How would I do this?

Here is the function I currently use:

```
    local info = UIDropDownMenu_CreateInfo()

    if level == 1 then
        for a,b in pairs(menuList) do
            info.text = b[1]
            info.hasArrow = b[2]

            UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info, level)
        end
    elseif level == 2 then

        for a,b in pairs(menuList[UIDROPDOWNMENU_MENU_VALUE][3]) do
            info.text = b
            info.func = OnClick

            UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info, level)
        end
    end
```

Here is the table example used:

```
testMenuList = {Greetings = {"Greetings", true, {"hi", "hello", "good day"}}, Farewells = {"Farewells", true, {"bye", "goodbye", "later"}}}
```

It can setup currently up to 2 levels down. The first and submenus.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: How come you e not setting the parent of level 2 to one of the menu level 1 items? Write it for three levels then you will see the pattern emerge.

Comment: I havent had to. Granted the dropdown menu itself has no text it does function without an issue. If I can set it like that then I would need an example.

Comment: You say "as far down as user supplies". Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to make the function for level 2 onward grab a similar nested table into the function. it would likely turn out to look something like this: {{"Greetings", true, {{"Hi", true, {"H", "i"}}, {"Hello", false, nil}}}} as you notice all sub elements would continue until subtables element 2 is all false.

Comment: Is the user a programmer giving you tables, or someone using the game UI adding things. There are many examples of table based menu helpers for WoW, so there is probably a ready and well used example depending on that you meant about the user part.

Comment: Programmer and no there is no such guide or this would be complete by now. It may not be possible in Lua...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function IOLib_CreateDropDown(parent, name, title, width, anchor, posX, posY, menuList, OnClick)
    local dropDown = CreateFrame("Button", name, parent, "UIDropDownMenuTemplate")
    --_G[name].list = menuList
    dropDown.list = menuList
    -- dropDown.Func = OnClick
    dropDown:ClearAllPoints()
    dropDown:SetPoint(anchor, posY, posX)

    local function initialize(self, level)
        local info = UIDropDownMenu_CreateInfo()

        if level ~= nil then
            info = UIDropDownMenu_CreateInfo()
            info.text = title
            info.isTitle = true
            UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info, level)

            if level == 1 then

                for a,b in pairs(menuList) do
                    info = UIDropDownMenu_CreateInfo()
                    info.text = b[1]
                    info.hasArrow = b[2]
                    info.func = OnClick
                    if info.hasArrow then _menuLists[b[1]] = b[3] end
                    UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info, level)
                end

            elseif level > 1 then
                --print(#_menuLists[UIDROPDOWNMENU_MENU_VALUE][2])
                --for x=1, #_menuLists[UIDROPDOWNMENU_MENU_VALUE] do
                for a,b in pairs(_menuLists[UIDROPDOWNMENU_MENU_VALUE]) do
                    info = UIDropDownMenu_CreateInfo()
                    info.text = b[1]
                    info.hasArrow = b[2]
                    if info.hasArrow then _menuLists[b[1]] = b[3] end
                    info.func = OnClick
                    UIDropDownMenu_AddButton(info, level)
                end
            end


        end
    end

    UIDropDownMenu_Initialize(dropDown, initialize)
    UIDropDownMenu_SetWidth(dropDown, width) -- Use in place of dropDown:SetWidth
    UIDropDownMenu_SetButtonWidth(dropDown, width + 24)
    UIDropDownMenu_SetSelectedID(dropDown, 1)
    UIDropDownMenu_JustifyText(dropDown, "LEFT")

    return dropDown
end
```

Here is an example of the table used with this function:

```
testMenuList = {{"Greetings", true, {{"Hi", true, {{"H", true, {{"Amazing", false, nil}}},{"i", false, nil}}},
                                     {"Hello", false, nil}}},
                {"Farewells", true, {{"Bye", false, nil},
                                     {"Goodbye", false, nil}}},
                {"Test", false, nil}}
```